# Play Buttons for each music seperatly

Tags: javascript, html, button

Play and pause functionalities work well with the 'playBtn' button, as indicated by the code 'const playBtn = document.querySelector(".play-btn");'. Additionally, I want the code 'const boxPlayBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".playbtn");' ensures that the same functionality extends to multiple buttons with the class 'playbtn.' When a button is clicked, it plays the song, and clicking the same button again pauses that specific song.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Progress bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-container">
        <div id="logo-prepdpriprava" class="logo-prepdpriprava"></div>
        <div id="menu"><a href="#">MENU</a></div>
        <div id="music-player">
        
            <audio src="Music/Come Together.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
            <div class="music-data-player">
                <div class="musician-song">
                    <h4 class="musician">The beatles</h4>
                    <h5 class="music-title">Hey Jude</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="timer-cont">
                    <p class="timer">0:00</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progression">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="player-btns">
            <button class="prev-btn">PREV</button>
            <button class="play-btn">  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="23" viewBox="0 0 11 23" fill="none" class="playsymbol">
                <path d="M10.333 11.5L0.583008 22.3253L0.583008 0.674683L10.333 11.5Z" fill="white"/>
                </svg></button>
            <button class="next-btn">NEXT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="section-1-content">
            <div class="squares">
                <div class="blue4BE0FC"><div></div></div>
                <div class="B81BEE"><div></div></div>
                <div class="FEC602"><div></div></div>
                <div class="two-squares">
                    <div class="FEC602-2"><div></div></div>
                    <div class="A4979FF"><div></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="blue4BE0FC"><div></div></div>
                <div class="B81BEE"><div></div></div>
                <div class="two-squares">
                    <div class="FEC602"><div></div></div>
                    <div class="A4979FF"><div></div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="blue4BE0FC"><div></div></div>

            </div>

            <div class="intro-banner">
                <div class="main-title">
                    <h1>20 MUSICIANS<br> 7 TRACKS OVER<br> 2000 VINYL<br> LOREM IPSUM</h1>
                </div>
    
                <div class="intro-banner-desc">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate libero et velit interdum.
                    </p>
                    <p>Ac aliquet odio mattis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur tempus urna at turpis condimentum lobortis. Curabitur tempus urna at turpis condimentum lobortis. Curabitur tempus urna at turpis condimentum lobortis.</p>
                    <p>Curabitur tempus urna at turpis condimentum lobortis.</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="section-2-content">
            <div class="music-container">
                <h2>POPULAR TRACKS</h2>

                <div class="music-boxes">
                    <div id="beatles" class="music-box">
                        <div class="before-img-content">
                            <div class="img-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="music-data">
                            <h3 class="music-musician-box">BEATLES</h3>
                            <p class="music-title-box">COME TOGETHER</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="playbtn">
                            <svg width="50" height="50" fill="none">
                                <path d="M25 0C11.2 0 0 11.2 0 25s11.2 25 25 25 25-11.2 25-25S38.8 0 25 0zm-5 36.25v-22.5L35 25 20 36.25z" fill="#fff">
                                </path></svg>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
                    <div id="bonjovi" class="music-box">
                        <div class="before-img-content">
                            <div class="img-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="music-data">
                            <h3 class="music-musician-box">BON JOVI</h3>
                            <p class="music-title-box">LIVING ON A PRAYER</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="playbtn">
                            <svg width="50" height="50" fill="none">
                                <path d="M25 0C11.2 0 0 11.2 0 25s11.2 25 25 25 25-11.2 25-25S38.8 0 25 0zm-5 36.25v-22.5L35 25 20 36.25z" fill="#fff">
                                </path></svg>
                        </div>
                   
                    </div>
                    <div id="gunsnroses" class="music-box">
                        <div class="before-img-content">
                            <div class="img-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="music-data">
                            <h3 class="music-musician-box">GUNS N' ROSES</h3>
                            <p class="music-title-box">DON'T CRY</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="playbtn">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none">
                                <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white"/>
                                <path d="M37.2366 24.9981L18.696 38.2856L18.282 12.3081L37.2366 24.9981Z" fill="#F0583D"/>
                                </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="foofighters" class="music-box">
                        <div class="before-img-content">
                            <div class="img-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="music-data">
                            <h3 class="music-musician-box">FOO FIGHTERS</h3>
                            <p class="music-title-box">EVERLONG</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="playbtn">
                            <svg width="50" height="50" fill="none">
                                <path d="M25 0C11.2 0 0 11.2 0 25s11.2 25 25 25 25-11.2 25-25S38.8 0 25 0zm-5 36.25v-22.5L35 25 20 36.25z" fill="#fff">
                                </path></svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="redhotchilipeopers" class="music-box">
                        <div class="before-img-content">
                            <div class="img-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="music-data">
                            <h3 class="music-musician-box">RED HOT CHILI PEPPER</h3>
                            <p class="music-title-box">CALIFORNICATION</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="playbtn">
                            <svg width="50" height="50" fill="none">
                                <path d="M25 0C11.2 0 0 11.2 0 25s11.2 25 25 25 25-11.2 25-25S38.8 0 25 0zm-5 36.25v-22.5L35 25 20 36.25z" fill="#fff">
                                </path></svg>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="metalica" class="music-box">
                        <div class="before-img-content">
                            <div class="img-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="music-data">
                            <h3 class="music-musician-box">METELICA</h3>
                            <p class="music-title-box">THE UNFORGIVABLE</p>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="playbtn">
                            <svg width="50" height="50" fill="none">
                                <path d="M25 0C11.2 0 0 11.2 0 25s11.2 25 25 25 25-11.2 25-25S38.8 0 25 0zm-5 36.25v-22.5L35 25 20 36.25z" fill="#fff">
                                    
                                </path></svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>

    </section>



   
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

**JS**

```
const musicContainer= document.querySelector(".header-container");
const musician=document.querySelector(".musician");
const musicTitle=document.querySelector(".music-title");
const progress=document.querySelector(".progress");
const timer=document.querySelector(".timer");
const progression=document.querySelector(".progression");
const prevBtn=document.querySelector(".prev-btn");
const nextBtn=document.querySelector(".next-btn");
const playBtn=document.querySelector(".play-btn");
const audio=document.querySelector("audio");
const boxPlayBtns=document.querySelectorAll(".playbtn");

const songs=["Come Together","Livin' On A Prayer","Don't Cry", "Everlong", "Californication", "The Unforgiven"];

let songIndex=1;
let isPlaying = false;

let pause = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="20" viewBox="0 0 14 20" fill="none" class="pausesymbol">
<line x1="2" x2="2" y2="20" stroke="white" stroke-width="4"/>
<line x1="12" x2="12" y2="20" stroke="white" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>`;

let pauseSymbol = `<svg width="50" height="50" fill="none"><path d="M25 0C11.2 0 0 11.2 0 25s11.2 25 25 25 25-11.2 25-25S38.8 0 25 0zm-2.5 35h-5V15h5v20zm10 0h-5V15h5v20z" fill="#fff"></path></svg>`;





let playSymbol = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="23" viewBox="0 0 11 23" fill="none" class="playsymbol">
<path d="M10.333 11.5L0.583008 22.3253L0.583008 0.674683L10.333 11.5Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>`;




loadSong(songs[songIndex]);

function loadSong(song){
    musicTitle.innerText=song;
    audio.src=`Music/${song}.mp3`;

    if(song==="Livin' On A Prayer"){
        musician.textContent="Bon Jovi";
    }else if(song==="Come Together"){
        musician.textContent="The Beatles";
    }else if(song==="Don't Cry"){
        musician.textContent="GUNS N' ROSES";
    }
    else if(song==="Everlong"){
        musician.textContent="FOO FIGHTERS";
    } else if(song==="Californication"){
        musician.textContent="RED HOT CHILI PEPPER";
    }
    else if(song==="The Unforgiven"){
        musician.textContent="Metalica";
    }
}

function playSong(){
    playBtn.innerHTML=pause;
    audio.play();
    songTimeUpdate();
}

function pauseSong(){
    playBtn.innerHTML=playSymbol;
    audio.pause();
}




function nextSong(){
    songIndex++;

    if(songIndex>5){
        songIndex=0;
    }
    loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
    playSong();
}

function prevSong(){
    songIndex--;

    if(songIndex<0){
        songIndex=songs.length-1;
    }
    loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
    playSong();
}

function setProgress(e){
    const width=this.clientWidth;
    const clickX= e.offSetX;
    console.log(clickX);
    const duration= audio.duration;

    audio.currentTime=(clickX/width)*duration;
}

function updateProgress(e){
    const {duration, currentTime}=e.srcElement;
    console.log(duration);
    console.log(currentTime);
    const progressPercent=(currentTime/duration)*100;
    progression.style.width=`${progressPercent}%`;
}




function playPauseSong(){
    if(isPlaying){
        playSong();
    }else{
        pauseSong();
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
}

function songTimeUpdate() {
    const duration = audio.duration;
    const currentTime = audio.currentTime;

    const minutes = Math.floor(currentTime / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor(currentTime % 60);

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" +seconds;
    }

    const totalTime = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    timer.innerText = totalTime;
}




boxPlayBtns.forEach((button, index)=>{
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    songIndex=index;
    loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
    playPauseSong();
    

})

})




playBtn.addEventListener("click",playPauseSong);
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", prevSong);
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", nextSong);

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    updateProgress(event);
    songTimeUpdate();
});



audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgress);
audio.addEventListener("ended", nextSong)

progress.addEventListener("click", setProgress);
```

Solution of a problem that I cant find so far

Comment: You can just call `loadSong` function on click of `. playbtn` by getting correct song element from the array based on your click.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).